# How to make list video when you use div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a Player and list player like Youtube but i use tag div replace tag video. Here is my code i'm download from Projekktor.com

```
<div id="player_aa" class="projekktor"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    projekktor('#player_aa', {
    poster: 'media/intro.png',
    playerFlashMP4: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
    width: 800,
    height: 450,
    playlist: [
        {
        0: {src: "media/trailer3.mp4", type: "video/mp4"},
        }
    ]    
    }, function(player) {} // on ready 
    );
});
</script>
</div>
```

I try use MenuBox but it dont work when i click. Now i want make list video how ? Any suggestion ? I need help faster

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What code do you need help with?  There are lots of ways to accomplish lists...

Comment: i just need make 1 more div -> float:right then show list video, each video when click on it my <div id="player_aa" class="projekktor"></div> show my video. I'm new developer. Just tell me the best or easy way to do that